# How to retrieve Chrome bookmarks and saved passwords without running Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, chromium

I uninstalled Chromium without exporting the bookmarks and the saved passwords. The appdata folders still exist. Is there a way to retrieve bookmarks and the saved passwords? I am on Windows 10.

I don't want to reinstall Chromium. The latest build screwed up my touchpad functioning and made my laptop unusable.

Comment: Did you connect and synchronise your Google account?

Comment: No, I don't use a Google account with the browser.

Comment: Chrome saved its data in SQLite database, on Windows in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases` (or other profile than `Default`). Not sure what you mean by "retrieve" then, you can browse the database.